# Does GWT and/or SmartGWT provide an implementation of CSS selectors?

Tags: gwt, css-selectors, smartgwt, xpath

I've seen [GWT's `getElementById`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById(java.lang.String)), but I'm looking for something a lot more flexible/powerful. I'd prefer CSS selectors, but an XPath interface would do in a pinch. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in [GWTQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/), a clone of JQuery's functionality (including selectors) to GWT, written by a GWT engineer.